# Poset with no smallest element but with a unique minimal element

Tags: order-theory

I'm trying to find a poset with no smallest element, but with a unique minimal element.

I'm defining $a$ to be a minimal element with respect to the relation $\prec$ if $(x \prec a) \implies (x=a)$ and that $a$ is the smallest element if $a \prec x$ for all $x$.

This is what I have:

"Consider the the pair $(X, R)$, where $X=\mathbb{Z} \cup \{i\}$, and $R:= xRy \iff$ either $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x<y$ or $x,y \in \{i\}$ and $x=y$.
Then $R$ is a partial ordering, and $X$ clearly has no smallest element.
Since no element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is comparable to $i$, then it must be that $i$ is the unique minimal element required."

Does this seem correct?

Comment: yes, I understand your example now.  I must have been thinking of lattices and hadn't recognized yet that $i$ is incomparable to anything but itself.  In that case, I'm inclined to agree with your result.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Are your partial orderings reflexive or irreflexive? I ask because your relation $R$ seems to be irreflexive on $\mathbb Z$ and reflexive on $\{i\}$. Apart from that, I think you've got the right idea, this is the same example I would have come up with. Maybe I would have just used negative integers instead of $\mathbb Z$.